# retrieve large amount of data from multiple tables within seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following query retrieves data from multiple tables.

There is a problem, as the data increases the amount of time to retrieve the data increases too ( the number of rows has reached to 20 thousand and it takes more than a minute to show the result).

i have used stored procedure but the result was same. Any Solution ?

```
Select TransactionDate,
    T.InvoiceNo,
    T.TotalAmount,
    PCost.TotalCostPrice ,
    (T.TotalAmount - PCost.TotalCostPrice) as TProfit,
    P.PaidAmount, P.Balance,
    CONCAT(Lastname, ', ', Firstname, ' ', Middlename) as Cashier,
    ISNULL(P.DiscountAmount,0),
    ISNULL(P.ProfitAmount,0),
    CustomerInfo
FROM [Transaction] T 
INNER JOIN TransactionPayment P ON T.InvoiceNo = P.InvoiceNo 
INNER JOIN Employee E ON T.EmployeeID =  E.EmployeeID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                SELECT  SUM(p.CostPrice*tl.Quantity) as TotalCostPrice,
                        tl.InvoiceNo 
                FROM Product p 
                INNER JOIN TransactionLineItem   tl ON p.ProductID = tl.ProductID 
                INNER JOIN [Transaction] T ON T.InvoiceNo = tl.InvoiceNo 
                WHERE TransactionDate >= @DateFrom AND TransactionDate <= @DateTo 
                GROUP BY tl.InvoiceNo
            )   as PCost ON PCost.InvoiceNo = T.InvoiceNo 
WHERE TransactionDate >= @DateFrom AND TransactionDate <= @DateTo
```

Comment: Without execution plan shown, there are only guesses on how to improve the query. Any ORM used?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create index IX_Transaction_TransactionDate
on dbo.[Transaction] (TransactionDate, InvoiceNo);
```

Comment: i have created the index on transaction table but the result is same

Comment: Are your DateFrom and DateTo local variables or input parameters of stored procedure? Try using OPTION(RECOMPILE) at the end of the query. Just for testing purposes.

Comment: those are input parameters.

Comment: Then your query is not selective enough to use index seek. Can you post the query plan you get here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?